# Silverstripe nivo slider

Tags: silverstripe, nivo-slider

```
if (class_exists('DataObjectManager'))
    $a='DataObjectManager';
else
    $a='ComplexTableField';
$f->addFieldToTab(
    "Root.Content.Panels",
    new $a(
        $this,
        'Panels',
        'NivoSliderPanel',
        array('Name' => 'Name','Thumbnail' => 'Thumbnail'),
        'getCMSFields_forPopup'
    )
);
```

i am using a nivo silder can anyone help me to understand is piece of code.
I am getting a error ComplexTableField could not found.

Comment: What version of SilverStripe are you using?

Answer (score 1):

`ComplexTableField` is from Silverstripe 2.4 and no longer works in 3.0 or 3.1.

If you are getting an error that ComplexTableField could not found then I am guessing you are using Silverstripe 3.1.

Silverstripe 2.4 code will not work in 3.1. This code needs modification to work in 3.1.

In Silverstripe 3.1 `GridField` has replaced `ComplexTableField`.

Using GridField looks something like this:

```
private static $has_many = array (
    'Panels' => 'Panel'
);

public function getCMSFields()
{
    $fields = parent::getCMSFields();

    $panelsField = new GridField(
        'Panels',
        'Panels',
        $this->Panels(),
        GridFieldConfig_RecordEditor::create()
    ); 
    $fields->addFieldToTab('Root.Panels', $panelsField);

    return $fields;
}
```

Comment: what to use instead of CompositeField..?

Comment: Why do you ask that? CompositeField still works in Silverstripe 3.1: http://api.silverstripe.org/3.1/class-CompositeField.html

Comment: Call to a member function addComponent() on a non-object: I am getting this error

Comment: how to show Datepicker in datefield..?? I changed in yml file but it is not reflecting on datefield